# Given $\frac{3a+4}{2a+3}$, how do we show that it is $>a$ if $a^2<2$, without knowing about this relationship beforehand?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given an expression such as

$$\frac{3a+4}{2a+3}\tag{1}$$

How do we show that it is $>a$ if $a^2<2$?

If we simply set

$$\frac{3a+4}{2a+3}>a\tag{2}$$

Then we easily obtain

$$a^2<2\tag{3}$$

But what if we didn't know of the inequality in $(2)$ beforehand? How could we reach it starting from just $1$?

**Here is some context on how this question came up.**

I am solving a problem in Chapter 22 "Infinite Sequences" of Spivak's *Calculus*.

In Problem $7b$ we are tasked with showing that

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=\sqrt{2}\tag{4}$$

where $a_n$ is defined recursively by

$$a_1=1$$

$$a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{1+a_n}$$

I won't go through the entire proof, but at some point the solution manual uses the following relationship

$$a_{n+2}=1+\frac{1}{1+a_{n+1}}=\frac{3a_n+4}{2a_n+3}$$

and simply says

$$a_{n+2}=\frac{3a_n+4}{2a_n+3}=\begin{cases} >a_n\text{ for } a_n^2<2 \\ <a_n\text{ for } a_n^2>2\end{cases}\tag{5}$$

My question arose because it seems that $(5)$ was pulled out of thin air, and I was wondering how one would come by it without knowing it beforehand.

Comment: It's not clear how you know right away that $\frac{3a+4}{2a+3} > 2$. Even if it's true, it's not equivalent to $a^2 < 2$. Also, why would you need to know that $\frac{3a+4}{2a+3} > a$ beforehand if that's what you're trying to prove?

Comment: Try subtracting $a$ from your fraction and showing that the difference is greater than $0$

Comment: @Accelerator There is a typo in the question (note that the title is correct). I want to prove that $\frac{3a+4}{2a+3}>a$. I will add some context so that I can avoid the current barrage of downvoting.

Comment: The title says, "Given $\frac{3a+4}{2a+3}$, how do we show that it is $> a$ if $a^2 < 2$." That basically means, "Let $a^2 < 2$. Prove $\frac{3a+4}{2a+3}$ > a. You start the proof by automatically assuming $\frac{3a+4}{2a+3} > a$, which you can't do, and it's what you need to prove.

Comment: Note that for the expression to make sense, we need to have $a\ne-\frac 32$. Can we take that for granted?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think that's trivial (IMO, but maybe not obvious to others), because $a^2 < 2$ means $a \in \left(-\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2}\right)$, and $-3/2$ isn't in that interval.

Comment: @Accelerator I've tried to improve the title to reflect the new context I have given about the actual problem in Spivak's Calculus involving Sequences that I am working on.

Comment: You have a typo in the second equation above equation (5). You left off a '1 +' in front of the fractional expression.

Comment: I believe it is correct currently, right?

Comment: Not yet, just above sth remains to be corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is about deriving $(2)$ under the assumption $(3)$.

Assume $a^2 <2\,$ which means $\,\sqrt 2 >a> -\sqrt 2\,$, in particular
$\,a>-1.5\iff 2a+3>0\,$.
Then
$$3a+4 \:>\: 2a^2+3a \:=\: a\,(2a+3)\,,$$
and the claimed inequality follows.

Answer (score 2):

I argue that with respect to intuition, in the context of this problem, you would start by looking at $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{1+a_n}$. Knowing well, that this is supposed to converge to $\sqrt{2}\approx 1.41$, we compute the first few values $a_1=1$, $a_2=1.5$, $a_3=1.4$ until we realize  that this oscillates around $\sqrt 2$. This is not an all too convenient property when we want to establish convergence. Then we realize that every second value is below $\sqrt{2}$, and moreover increasing. This is a very convenient property. With this motivation, we compute $a_{n+2}=\frac{3a_n+4}{2a_n+3}$.

Now comes the important part. With this motivation we *want* to show that $a_{n+2}>a_n$ if $a_n^2<2$, i.e. prove our observation that the sequence is indeed increasing and stays below $\sqrt{2}$ when we start below $\sqrt{2}$. This we want to do, because we know that we can then use that an increasing sequence bounded from above (by $\sqrt{2}$) does indeed converge, which gives the first important part, the existence of the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{2n+1}$. The proof for $a_{2n}$ (above $\sqrt{2}$) is analogous.

**EDIT**:
The explanation above addresses the statement that Equation (5) seemed to be pulled out of thin air. Here's a very explicit answer to the main question.

Suppose you are given $a\in\mathbb R$ such that $a^2<2$. Further, you are given $f(a)=\frac{3a+4}{2a+3}$. That's it. This means, you are provided information, but no *claim*. Now, you can start playing around with this information, you can look at the function in WolframAlpha (which, in fact, will give you a lot of information), but it's very unlikely that you will come up with the conclusion $f(a)>a$. In fact, if you start looking for a lower bound, you will most likely use that $f$ is concave and thus $f((1-\alpha)(-\sqrt{2})+\alpha\sqrt{2})\ge(1-\alpha)f(-\sqrt 2)+\alpha f(\sqrt{2})$, which is significantly better. Sometimes it happens, yes, but usually we don't find useful results by coincidence.

Now, let's assume you're also given the claim.
Suppose you are given $a\in\mathbb R$ such that $a^2<2$. Further, you are given $f(a)=\frac{3a+4}{2a+3}$. Show that $f(a)>a$.

Let's look at two very common ways to approach this.
You can start with $a^2<2$ and try to derive $f(a)>a$, the forward approach. Or, you can start with $f(a)>a$ and try to resolve it into an easier claim C. This means that you come up with C, then you show that C implies $f(a)>a$ (coming up with C and showing that C implies $f(a)>a$ may or may not be the same process), then you try to derive C from the assumptions. This is the backward approach. Here, as you stated, it is not easy to see how to get to $f(a)>a$ from $a^2<2$. Try the other approach, take $f(a)>a$, notice that this is *equivalent* to $(3a+4)>a(2a+3)$ using that $a>-3/2$. Looks easier already. The remaining steps are clear, so you arrive at the *equivalent* assumption $a^2<2$, where you actually try to simplify the claim.

Here's an example where it's reasonable to combine both approaches.
Let $x\in\mathbb R$ be such that $\tan^{-1}(x)\le x$. Show that $(4x+1)^3-1\ge 0$. First, the claim can be simplified, it is equivalent to $x\ge 0$. This is a lot easier to deal with. That's the backwards approach. Then, we take the forward approach.
Recall that $-\pi/2<\tan^{-1}<\pi/2$, so the inequality implies that $x>-\pi/2$, for $x\ge\pi/2$ we do have $x\ge 0$ (here, it's very useful that we simplified the claim) and are done, for $-\pi/2<x<\pi/2$ we can apply $\tan$ since it is increasing, so we get $x\le\tan(x)$ equivalently, then we take two derivatives of $\tan$, notice that $x=0=\tan(0)$, $g'(0)=1=\tan'(0)$ with $g(x)=x$, that $\tan''(x)>0$ for $x>0$ and $\tan''(x)<0$ for $x<0$, so $\tan(x)\ge x$ if and only if $x\ge 0$. Done.

The message: It is *crucial* to combine these (and other) approaches when proofs get increasingly difficult. Don't avoid it, embrace it, it makes life easier. If this wasn't the problem, if the problem was that you wondered how to get to the result without having a claim, it's *crucial* to have a claim. Unless you don't know where you're going, you can't expect to arrive there. If you wanted to know how to come up with the claim, that's what I answered in the first place. In fact, here the claim exists *before* the function $f(a)=\frac{3a+4}{2a+3}$ does, because the reason you look at every second member of the sequence is to obtain monotonicity, i.e. $a_{n+2}>a_n$. So, when you actually design the proof, the claim is already there.

Comment: Your arguments and points reached are precisely the ones that are made and reached as one moves through the items of Problem 7 in Chapter 22 of Spivak's Calculus. You've explained why we would want to show that $a_{n+2}>a_n$.

Comment: And I never even saw the book! I hope this answers how they pulled this from thin air. Or is my explanation so close to the solution that it leaves you with the same question?

Comment: I updated the answer. I hope that this covers every aspect of your question.

Answer (score 0):

$2a+3>0$ when $-\sqrt{2}<a<\sqrt{2}$. So given $a^2-2<0$, we have $\frac{2a^2-4}{2a+3}<0$, $\frac{2a^2+3a-3a-4}{2a+3}<0$ and hence $\frac{3a+4}{2a+3}>a.$